# Solution of Klein-Gordon field in Schwarzschild metric

Tags: black-holes, klein-gordon-equation

I was trying to understand the behavior of scalar field in the vicinity of black hole and I set up the Klein-Gordon equation in the background of Schwarzschild metric. But I am having difficulty in solving this equation exactly. Also, I could only find asymptotic solutions in the literature.

Could any one please help me on this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be related to your question: [Klein Gordon equation in tortoise coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304184/klein-gordon-equation-in-tortoise-coordinates).

Comment: See

https://researchers.dellmed.utexas.edu/en/publications/scattering-of-massless-scalar-waves-by-a-schwarzschild-singularit

and

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/scattering-from-black-holes/1119267BC3D50792E67F4176AA74006B

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are having difficulties, the resulting differential equation is not trivial:

$$r(r-1)y''(r)+(2 r-1)y'(r)-r^2 q^2 y(r)=0 $$

(where q is a constant). Nevertheless, you can analyze it numerically using Mathematica or Matlab.

But the problem is already solved: asymptotic expressions in terms of Whittaker functions were found by Rowan and Stephenson in 1977 (See J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. Vol 10, n. 1, pp. 15-23). A more general solutions has recently been found by  Bezerra et al. (see [arXiv:1312.4823](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4823)) in terms of Confluent Heun functions. They solve the more complicated Kerr-Newman metric, for a black hole carrying charge and angular momentum, but I think you could apply this solution to the Schwarzschild metric by taking $Q=0$ and $L=0$ in their equations.